# dojo dgrid not rendering

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I'm a newbie at js frameworks and trying out Dojo currently to see if its best for our project.
I'm struggling to get things working with Dojo.
I attempted using Dojo's dgrid.The code is more or less a straight lift off from the tutorials and I believe I have all the dependecies too (like dgrid/xstyle and put-selector).Still I don't see the grid rendering on the page.Can someone please help me with this.

Here is my js setup(in tomcat)

[image]
and here is my code(almost straight lift off from the tutorial section)

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial: Hello dgrid!</title>
    <!-- this configuration assumes that the dgrid package is located
         on the filesystem as a sibling to the dojo package -->

<!-- load Dojo -->

<script>
    dojoConfig ={
    baseUrl: "js",
    isDebug: true, // enables debug
    async: true, // enables AMD loader
    packages: [
        {
        "name": "dojo",
        "location": "lib/dojo"
        },
        {
        "name": "dgrid",
        "location": "lib/dgrid"
        }   
    ]
    };
</script>
<script src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script>
require(["dojo/parser", "dgrid/Grid", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Grid){
            alert("Hi");
            var data = [
                        { first: "Bob", last: "Barker", age: 89 },
                        { first: "Vanna", last: "White", age: 55 },
                        { first: "Pat", last: "Sajak", age: 65 }
                    ];
            var grid = new Grid(
                    { 
                         columns : {
                                first: "First Name",
                                last: "Last Name",
                                age: "Age"
                            }
                    }, "grid");
            grid.renderArray(data);            
        });
</script>

</head>
<body class="slate">
    <div id="grid" class="slate"></div>
    Hi grid
</body>
</html>
```

here is what i see(i don't see the grid at all and there are no js errors too).
[image]

Comment: In the script tag that loads dojo, the src attribute doesn't point to the js/lib folder. Try <script src="js/lib/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

Comment: Couple of things, with your setup you don't need to add packages or baseUrl. Just set <script="js/lib/dojo/dojo.js"></script> as psema4 wrote. Also: If you want to parse the page for widgets you also need to call parser.parse(); in your function. I know it's not needed for what you have now, but later when you add widgets you will wonder why it doesn't work.

Comment: are you sure that there aren't errors in browser's console?

Answer (score 0):

in Grid there is "dojo/parser" because the first require isn't Grid.
Try with

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dgrid/Grid", "dojo/domReady!"], function(parser,Grid){
```

or

```
  require([ "dgrid/Grid", "dojo/parser","dojo/domReady!"], function(Grid){
```